# Magento 1.9.3.1 getSpecialPrice

Tags: magento-1.9, price, catalog, special-price

I have set different **user groups** on my store. If you are regular account or logged out you see regular prices. For special clients there are special prices set (**user group prices, not special price**). But when I also set special price to product, then it automatically overwrites the user group price and dont show 'special price' tag in front of it. If it is bigger than user group price then it does'nt do anything (and that is how I want it to be).

I need it to display **'special price'** in front of the user group price if special price is even lower than user group price. For that I need to call that price out in my template that I set in admin panel as 'special price'. But I cant seem to find the right callout for that. **getSpecialPrice() or specialPrice()** just return 0.

Im using the **base->default->catalog->product->price.phtml** as the template.

```
              <!-- Get group Id -->
          <?php $groupId = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerGroupId(); ?>
         <!-- Get customer Group name -->
          <?php $group = Mage::getModel('customer/group')->load($groupId); ?>
      <?php if($group->getCode() == "Hulgiklient"): ?>
          <!-- kuva special price regu price all, kui hulgiklient -->
          <div class="price-box">
              <!-- <span class="price-label"><?php echo $this->__('Regular Price:') ?></span> -->
              <span class="price" id="old-price-<?php echo $_id ?><?php echo $this->getIdSuffix() ?>">
                  <?php echo $_coreHelper->formatPrice($_finalPrice, false) ?>
              </span>
          </div>
      <?php else: ?>
          <p class="old-price">
              <span class="price-label"><?php echo $this->__('Regular Price:') ?></span>
              <span class="price" id="old-price-<?php echo $_id ?><?php echo $this->getIdSuffix() ?>">
                  <?php echo $_coreHelper->formatPrice($_regularPrice, false) ?>
              </span>
          </p>
      <?php endif; ?>


          <?php if ($_taxHelper->displayBothPrices()): ?>
            <p class="special-price">
                <span class="price-label"><?php echo $_specialPriceStoreLabel ?></span>
                <span class="price-excluding-tax">
                    <span class="label"><?php echo $this->helper('tax')->__('Excl. Tax:') ?></span>
                    <span class="price"
                          id="price-excluding-tax-<?php echo $_id ?><?php echo $this->getIdSuffix() ?>">
                        <?php echo $_coreHelper->formatPrice($_finalPrice, false) ?>
                    </span>
                </span>
                <span class="price-including-tax">
                    <span class="label"><?php echo $this->helper('tax')->__('Incl. Tax:') ?></span>
                    <span class="price"
                          id="price-including-tax-<?php echo $_id ?><?php echo $this->getIdSuffix() ?>">
                        <?php echo $_coreHelper->formatPrice($_finalPriceInclTax, false) ?>
                    </span>
                </span>
            </p>
        <?php else: ?>

              <!-- Get group Id -->
              <?php $groupId = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerGroupId(); ?>
             <!-- Get customer Group name -->
              <?php $group = Mage::getModel('customer/group')->load($groupId); ?>
        <?php if($group->getCode() == "Hulgiklient"): ?>
              <!-- kuva special price regu price all, kui hulgiklient -->
              <!-- <p class="special-price">
                  <span class="price-label"><?php echo $_specialPriceStoreLabel ?></span>
              <span class="price" id="product-price-<?php echo $_id ?><?php echo $this->getIdSuffix() ?>">
              <?php  echo $_coreHelper->formatPrice($_finalPrice, false) ?>
              </span>
              </p> -->
        <?php else: ?>
              <p class="special-price">
                  <span class="price-label"><?php echo $_specialPriceStoreLabel ?></span>
              <span class="price" id="product-price-<?php echo $_id ?><?php echo $this->getIdSuffix() ?>">
                  <?php echo $_coreHelper->formatPrice($_finalPrice, false) ?>
              </span>
              </p>
        <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: I think this is the default way of working of Magento price. If it is not working like in your case, then that means some extensions customized magento's default price showing behaviour

Comment: @RajeevKTomy It is working like I described it, I just cant call out specialPrice(). regularPrice() and finalPrice() are working fine. I need the special price to compare it with final price, so it can decide whether to put 'special price' tag in front of it or no.

Comment: what type of products that your site holds ?

Comment: @RajeevKTomy simple products

Comment: how you are calling that functions. could you please add that to the question ?

Comment: @RajeevKTomy I added the part from price.phtml that I have edited. Im checking user groups because when user is logged in as wholesale customer, then it wont display the cheaper price as 'special price'

To clarify, I need to call out that 'special price' value that you can add to product from admin panel (the one where you also need to display the starting date and end date of that special price).